# Transformation of covariant derivate under conformal transformation of metri

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Suppose we have two spaces $X$ and $Y$ with metrics $g_X$ and $g_Y$ respectively.

Now suppose that the metrics are related by a conformal transformation $g_X = C g_Y$ where $C$ is some conformal factor.

Why would the covariant derivatives be related as $\nabla_X = g_X^{-1} \nabla_Y$?

Comment: Hey could you make your question a bit clearer? By spaces I assume you mean Riemannian manifolds? and are the covariant derivatives you're talking about the ones associated with the Levi-Civita connection ?

Comment: The connections of conformally related metrics are not generally the same. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Levi-Civita_connection) for some formulas relating them.

Comment: Yes, it should be Riemannian. In particular we are dealing with the Poincare disk and Euclidean space. The metrics on these spaces are conformally related by $g_P = 1/(1-r^2)^2 g_E$ according to Wikipedia. I am trying to derive the formula in the first image of this link: http://building-babylon.net/2018/04/10/gradient-optimisation-on-the-poincare-disc/